# results from an sqlachemy query as iterator

Tags: python, iterator, sqlalchemy, gensim

I am struggling to create an iterator from a query from sqlalchemy.

Here is what I tried so far

**create a table**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, MetaData, Table , Integer, String
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test90.db')
conn = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData()
myTable = Table('myTable', metadata,
     Column('Doc_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
     Column('Doc_Text', String))
metadata.create_all(engine)

conn.execute(myTable.insert(), [{'Doc_id': 1, 'Doc_Text' : 'first sentence'},
          {'Doc_id': 2, 'Doc_Text' : 'second sentence'},
          {'Doc_id': 3, 'Doc_Text' : 'third sentence'},
          {'Doc_id': 4, 'Doc_Text' : 'fourth sentence'}
          ])
```

I read everything I could on iterator but do not get it. 
Here the class I created to get an iterator but it does not work 
(it overflows although I specify a break)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class RecordsIterator:
def __init__(self, xDB, xSQL):
    self.engine = create_engine(xDB)
    self.conn = self.engine.connect()
    self.xResultCollection = self.conn.execute(xSQL)
def __iter__(self):
    return self 
def next (self):
    while self.xResultCollection.closed is False:
        xText = (self.xResultCollection.fetchone())[1]
        xText = xText.encode('utf-8')
        yield xText.split()
        if not self.xResultCollection:
            break


x1 = RecordsIterator(xDB = 'sqlite:///test91.db', xSQL = 'select * from myTable')
```

In case you are wondering why I am not just using a **generator** . 
I need to feed the iterator in gensim.Word2Vec and unfortunately, it does not take a generator

```
   import gensim
   gensim.models.Word2Vec(x1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks. see edits. gensim would not take it or am I missing something ?

Comment: posted an anser - as I can see from a quick look at the source of Word2Vec the problem is that generators are explicitly forbidden as the `sentences` argument. Probably there's some reason for that which I can't see because it shouldn't really make a difference. Maybe it has to do with the C optimizations...

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I think there is a problem in gensim word2vec tutorial http://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/

Comment: the difference is that in the tutorial `__iter__` returns a generator, in your code `__iter__` returns `self` and it's `next` method returns a generator.

Comment: thanks. cannot make sense of this. Will post it to gensim mailing group perhaps someone can there can help . It seems to be an issue many struggled with https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check `if not self.xResultCollection` will always return `False`, as the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the result object will always be `True`.

In your `next` method you have a for and a while loop, which shouldn't really be needed, the `next` method should just return one element, there's no need for a loop there.

As `self.xResultCollection` is itself an iterable you could just do:

```
class RecordsIterator:  
    def __init__(self, xDB, xSQL):
        self.engine = create_engine(xDB)
        self.conn = self.engine.connect()
        self.resultIterator = iter(self.conn.execute(xSQL))
    def __iter__(self):
        return self 
    def next (self):
        return next(self.resultIterator)[1].encode('utf-8').split()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For those interested in a using this with gensim.**

It turns out that the problem was that gensim wants an iterator, on which we can return (iterating over results of a query cursor, consumes it).

see discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/RpRh63xk4S8)

this is what seems to work for me

```
import gensim 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


xDB = 'sqlite:///test91.db'
xSQL = 'select * from myTable'
engine = create_engine(xDB)
conn = engine.connect()
xResultIterator = conn.execute(xSQL)


class MyIterator(object):
def __init__(self, xResults, xNrCol):
    self.xResults = xResults
    self.xNrCol = xNrCol
def __iter__(self):
    for xRecord in self.xResults:
        xText = (xRecord[self.xNrCol]).lower().encode('utf8')
        xToken = xText.split()
        if not xToken:
            continue
        yield xToken
    self.xResults = conn.execute(xSQL)  ### THIS SEEMS TO FIX IT 


#to use             

q1 = MyIterator(xResultIterator, xNrCol = 1)
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences = q1 , min_count = 1)
```

and here the vocabulary

```
model.vocab.keys()
```

I run this on a postgresql with 1 Million entries (titles of scientific papers) in about 90 seconds without problem 
I hope this will help someone else